# Search Array of Objects including child nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, search

I wish to search on an Array with nested Objects for any value and then return the object it was found in to place it into a new array.

Currently I have:

```
var json = {
    'offices': [{
        "home_id": "1",
        "price": "925",
        "sqft": "1100",
        "num_of_beds": "2",
        "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        "types": {
            "0": "Internet",
            "1": "msn",
            "2": "aol"
        }
    }, {
        "home_id": "2",
        "price": "1425",
        "sqft": "1900",
        "num_of_beds": "4",
        "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        "types": {
            "0": "Internet",
            "1": "google",
            "2": "virgin"
        }
    }]
}

var theOffices = json.offices;

var result = $.grep(theOffices, function (h) {
  return h.home_id == 1
    && h.price == 925
});

console.log(result)
```

I can use $.grep to search as shown above, however, this searches on the first object only, not the nested... I.e how would I extend this use of $.grep to iterate over the 'types' - say for instance to get 'msn' ??

HELP PLEASE :):) Been pulling hair out for last 6 hours!

Comment: You don't need to write this yourself, do you? Have you looked at a library such as lodash?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean you want to have a function you can call like `search(theOffices,'msn')` and have it return an array of all of the objects in which 'msn' appears as the value of a property, or the value of a property on any of its 'child' objects, at any depth?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array filter() to accomplish this.  Check out the following:

```js
var json = {
    'offices': [{
        "home_id": "1",
        "price": "925",
        "sqft": "1100",
        "num_of_beds": "2",
        "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        "types": {
            "0": "Internet",
            "1": "msn",
            "2": "aol"
        }
    }, {
        "home_id": "2",
        "price": "1425",
        "sqft": "1900",
        "num_of_beds": "4",
        "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        "types": {
            "0": "Internet",
            "1": "google",
            "2": "virgin"
        }
    }, {
        "home_id": "1",
        "price": "925",
        "sqft": "1980",
        "num_of_beds": "6",
        "num_of_baths": "9.5",
        "types": {
            "0": "InterNope",
            "1": "google",
            "2": "virgin"
        }
    }
  ]
}

var theOffices = json.offices;

var results = theOffices.filter( function(f) {
  return f.home_id == "1" && f.price == "925";
});

console.log("res");
console.log(results);
```